# Startup Taking unnecessary amount of time (UBUNTU 20.04 )

Tags: boot, 20.04, snap, startup, snap-store

This is the result of **systemd-analyze**

```
Startup finished in 3.660s (kernel) + 25min 52.291s (userspace) = 25min 55.952s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 26.548s in userspace
```

This is the result of **systemd-analyze blame**

```
25min 19.119s fstrim.service                                                                           
      39.730s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
      33.977s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                                           
      30.589s snapd.service                                                                            
      21.164s dev-sda4.device                                                                          
      17.877s systemd-rfkill.service                                                                   
      16.475s udisks2.service                                                                          
      15.692s networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
      13.629s NetworkManager.service                                                                   
      12.693s gdm.service                                                                              
      12.531s dev-loop30.device                                                                        
      12.419s dev-loop38.device                                                                        
      12.164s dev-loop34.device                                                                        
      11.980s dev-loop8.device                                                                         
      11.877s dev-loop32.device                                                                        
      11.859s dev-loop29.device                                                                        
      11.833s dev-loop26.device                                                                        
      11.814s dev-loop31.device                                                                        
      11.772s dev-loop37.device                                                                        
      11.611s dev-loop27.device                                                                        
      11.503s dev-loop28.device                                                                        
      11.387s dev-loop15.device                                                                        
      11.291s dev-loop33.device                                                                        
      11.204s dev-loop11.device                                                                        
      11.177s dev-loop12.device                                                                        
      11.147s dev-loop5.device                                                                         
      11.144s dev-loop21.device                                                                        
      11.144s dev-loop13.device                                                                        
      11.143s dev-loop16.device                                                                        
      11.143s dev-loop17.device                                                                        
      10.791s dev-loop35.device                                                                        
      10.382s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
      10.364s snapd.seeded.service
10.292s systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
      10.002s dev-loop10.device                                                                        
       9.951s dev-loop22.device                                                                        
       9.577s dev-loop14.device                                                                        
       9.575s dev-loop9.device                                                                         
       8.116s systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
       8.077s dev-loop0.device                                                                         
       7.949s dev-loop7.device                                                                         
       7.929s dev-loop1.device                                                                         
       7.571s snapd.apparmor.service                                                                   
       7.480s networking.service                                                                       
       7.038s ModemManager.service                                                                     
       6.971s thermald.service                                                                         
       6.933s dev-loop4.device                                                                         
       6.746s dev-loop6.device                                                                         
       6.190s dev-loop2.device                                                                         
       6.040s dev-loop3.device                                                                         
       4.758s apache2.service                                                                          
       4.602s accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
       4.005s gpu-manager.service                                                                      
       2.976s polkit.service                                                                           
       2.960s systemd-udevd.service                                                                    
       2.718s snap-atom-275.mount                                                                      
       2.701s snap-atom-282.mount                                                                      
       2.646s snap-core-11316.mount                                                                    
       2.642s snap-core-11420.mount                                                                    
       2.631s snap-core18-2074.mount                                                                   
       2.613s snap-core18-2128.mount                                                                   
       2.609s snap-core20-1081.mount                                                                   
       2.598s snap-core20-904.mount                                                                    
       2.583s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                                             
       2.553s snap-flutter-91.mount                                                                    
       2.539s rsyslog.service
```

Comment: Fstrim took 25 minutes to run, this is extremely slow - you should probably investigate if you have SDD problems - or maybe clean out some data.

Comment: @ArturMeinild , I think that is the total time it took to startup.
Lowkey I feel this is about Snap, although I am a complete beginner.